# Official 7-Zip for Linux on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, 7zip

As the official 7-Zip for Linux is out now, I would like to install it on my Ubuntu 20.04.
I have checked and I see that it's not available through the `apt` right now, but on the [7-Zip webpage](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) there is a `.tar.xz` file available. How am I able to install it in my system? Or is it just a portable version of the app which means it's ready to use after unpacking an archive? Thanks for tips.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: @Nmath Complementing your suggestion, now there's also this: https://snapcraft.io/p7zip-desktop

Comment: @Nmath As I wrote in a question, there is now 7-Zip for Linux from the author of the 7-Zip directly, not the p7zip which is port of the outdated 7-Zip 16.02. On the page linked there is a package of 7-Zip 21.07 with "new code with all changes from latest 7-Zip for Windows".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 7-Zip webpage provides several `tar.xz` files, including a source package and binary packages for various architectures.

If you download the binary package for your architecture you can just put the binary file into one of the directories in your search path. `/usr/local/bin` would be the canonical place.

Alternatively, you can download the source package and compile 7-Zip yourself.